# Android - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Theme.getKey() reflection exception

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

After uploading my app for closed testing the following exception is reported in the prelaunch report:

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Theme.getKey() reflection exception
  at aufa.b (aufa.java:10)
  at axbv.a (axbv.java:2)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.a (ComposableLambdaImpl.java:5)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.a (ComposeView.java)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.a (AbstractComposeView.java:2)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.a (ComposableLambdaImpl.java:5)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.c (CompositionLocalKt.java:19)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.a (CompositionLocalsKt.java:6)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.a (AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.java:2)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.a (ComposableLambdaImpl.java:5)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.c (CompositionLocalKt.java:19)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.a (AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.java:58)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.a (WrappedComposition.java:2)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.a (ComposableLambdaImpl.java:5)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.c (CompositionLocalKt.java:19)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.a (WrappedComposition.java:7)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.a (ComposableLambdaImpl.java:5)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.ActualJvm_jvmKt.a (ActualJvm_jvmKt.java:3)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.a (ComposerImpl.java:3)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.b (SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.java:6)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.U (ComposerImpl.java:15)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.e (Recomposer.java:11)
  at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.c (CompositionImpl.java:1)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.XA (WrappedComposition.java:5)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.c (WrappedComposition.java:4)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.afo (WrappedComposition.java:2)
  at bcx.a (bcx.java)
  at bcq.b (bcq.java:6)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.XA (WrappedComposition.java:6)
  at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow (AndroidComposeView.java:9)
  at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow (View.java:21307)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:4239)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:4246)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner (ViewGroup.java:6001)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView (ViewGroup.java:5777)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView (ViewGroup.java:5717)
  at bhnp.aac (bhnp.java:7)
  at bhmx.a (bhmx.java:5)
  at bhmj.g (bhmj.java:4)
  at bhnb.n (bhnb.java:4)
  at axcc.acF (axcc.java:3)
  at bde.c (bde.java:2)
  at bde.f (bde.java:1)
  at bdd.d (bdd.java:5)
  at bde.h (bde.java:3)
  at axeq.a (axeq.java:2)
  at axcd.b (axcd.java:3)
  at bhnb.aac (bhnb.java:3)
  at bhmx.a (bhmx.java:5)
  at bhol.a (bhol.java:5)
  at com.google.android.finsky.uipattern.base.render.RenderTreeHost$observer$1.p (RenderTreeHost.java)
  at androidx.lifecycle.FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.afo (FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.java:7)
  at bcx.a (bcx.java)
  at bcq.k (bcq.java:10)
  at bcq.h (bcq.java:2)
  at bcq.c (bcq.java)
  at dv.a (dv.java)
  at di.d (di.java:138)
  at cy.ar (cy.java:60)
  at cy.at (cy.java:8)
  at cy.aj (cy.java:7)
  at cl.run (cl.java)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8016)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1076)
Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.content.res.Resources$Theme.getKey []
  at java.lang.Class.getMethod (Class.java:2072)
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod (Class.java:2050)
  at aufa.b (aufa.java:8)
```

It seems like the exception is happening due to some composable view, but I am not using the jetpack compose in my project.

Minimum SDK: 21

Target SDK: 31

AGP Version: 4.1.3

Android Studio Version: Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1

What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: I got the same issue, the offending process is 'com.android.vending', so I suspect a bug in Google Play Store application installed in the testing devices.